# Ordered response with nominal predictors

Tags: survey, order-statistics, ordered-logit, categorical-data

I have a data set with ordered response variables (ten levels) and nominal independent variables (sex, year of birth, educational background etc. of the participants in a questionnaire).

How do I test the effect of the nominal predictors on each of the ordered responses?

I tried a ordinal logistic regression (`polr{MASS}`), following this example [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm), but ran into some trouble with R (`Error: initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite`). Is this method even valid, or should I try another one? I believe that my data set is a fairly common result of a survey, yet I have trouble to find any hints on how to analyse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the response variables are ordered and have ten levels, it is reasonable to treat these variables as continuous. (There is research indicating that from 6 levels the effects on statistics is minimal). This means you could use normal regression to start with.

For the nominal variables. If you mark them as factors in R, then R should take care of the rest.

Comment: So I could use a regular glm? (response ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3) And do I treat year of birth as nominal as well, or can I leave that as a continuous variable? Additionally, if I have hierarchical predictors (1st Question: Are you a citizen of this town? If Yes, then proceed to question two, if 'No' skip questions two and three and continue with #4), do I still include the original 1st question or just the follow ups?

Comment: These are a lot of questions that are not covered by your initial question. I cannot take you step by step all the way.